# How to specify BigQuery dataset location in R-Studio with bigrquery?

Tags: r, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, rstudio

I am new to R, and wanted to work with BigQuery in R studio using BigQuery package.

I am trying to run a simple query to BigQuery via Rstudio after our dataset location was changed from 'US' to 'australia-southeast1', and getting the below error:

```
'Error: Not found: Dataset projectId:GA was not found in location US [notFound]'
```

I have tried to specify the location with:

`bq_project_query(project, sql, location = 'australia-southeast1')`, but it didn't work.

```
project <- "projectId"

sql <- "SELECT fullVisitorId FROM `GA.ga_sessions_20190822` LIMIT 100"

test <- bq_project_query(project, sql)
bq_table_download(test, max_results = 10)
```

How can I specify the location of the dataset? I don't have the admin access to change the location of the dataset in BQ, and can't save the table in other properties....

I couldn't find any ways to resolve the problem..is there a workaround?

Comment: For trial and error purposes, you may want to try creating a dataset in other regions or multi-regional location (EU) other than the US then specify it as location=[location] e.g location=EU.

Comment: Hi @Christopher, thanks for suggestion! Can you specify where in that request should I put the query itself? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to specify the location:

```
library(DBI)
library(bigrquery)

con <- DBI::dbConnect(
  bigquery(),
  project = "NAME_PROJECT",
  dataset = "NAME_TABLE",
  billing = "BILLING", ##Billing must be enabled
)

mydata <- DBI:: dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM TABLE.DATASET")
```

The specification happens in the dbConnect script once you name the project and dataset. Hope this helps.